# how convert key value class to json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

i am a class with definition below

```
 public class Param
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }

        public Param(string key, object value)
        {
            this.Key = key;
            this.Value = value;
        }
    }
```

a objects with values

```
var params = new List<Param>(){new Param("k1","v1"),new Param("k2","v2"),new Param("k3","v3")};
```

How to build a json with this structure.

```
{
"k1":"v1",
"k2":"v2",
"k3":"v3"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(params.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value));
```